# post for specific group in Facebook for new changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, facebook-graph-api

it is been few days that I can not post a message from my app to specific groups of friends in Facebook, I am using asp.net MVC, before that I was using following code to post for only one list of friends " for example: close friend" but now it always post to all friends even when I specify target group.

```
    FacebookClient fpost1 = new FacebookClient(context.AccessToken.ToString());
    fpost1.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "test message", to = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" });
```

what should be changed to post for only specific list. consider xxxxxxxxxxxx as a close friend list id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app is a website, the easiest way to do this is to just use the share button and let the user pick the group he wants to post to.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

If your app is mobile, you can use the Share Dialog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share